# RenameTo seems to fail randomly

Tags: java, file-rename

There is a lot of post about RenameTo, but infortunately none of it seems to be my problem or answer it :'(

My problem is: i give a file to my prog, then it shoud encrypt it, calculate the hash of the encrypted file, and rename this encrypted file with this hash. 
To do it, i first create the encrypted file with the name "tmp", then i calculate his name (with the call "myfile.setFileID()" in the code below) and then i use RenameTo to rename it.

The encryption work well, the hashfunction too (no doubt here, i used both for a while before trying to implement that). In fact, everything works well....except sometimes RenameTo fail. And i don't know why.

Here's the part of code where i use RenameTo:

```java
            //encrypt file:
            File tmpEncryptedFile = Crypt.encrypt(originalFile, aesKey);

            //set File ID and rename file: 
            myfile.setFileID(tmpEncryptedFile);
            File encryptedFile = new File(myfile.getFileID());
            if(!tmpEncryptedFile.renameTo(encryptedFile)) {
                System.err.println("unable to rename file. Upload failed. Please try again.");
            }
```

Sometimes it works well, sometimes i got the "unable to rename file". Each time, the tmp file is correctly created, so it seems that really comes from renameTo. 
Plus, i've runned a lot of tests now, and it can fail or work with the same file input (oh, except that the encrypted file will not be the same even for the same input file, since the key is random...so yes, the input for RenameTo is not the same, but i mean it's not a "file not found" problem or a problem from another part of my program).

For example, i can run the program  times, each times giving it the same file, and the two first time fails, the third one works well. Or i can run it 10 times, the 9 first times works well and the last one fail. Since the fails appears to be random, i can't understand what doesn't work here.

I've read that i could maybe use Files.move() instead, but it seems more "logical" to me to use RenameTo() and i would like to understand what is wrong here. Plus, Files.move() use a path, and i just want it to be done in my project directory so the file name is enough for me.

Comment: Have you checked for space issue , rename fails if no space available?
Other could be that encryptedFile is already available and is in use so you cannot create another file with same name , check if file exist before renaming

Comment: What characters can appear in the new filename? Are all of those supported by the filesystem you use?

Comment: i've tried a "encryptedFile.exists()" after the line File encryptedFile = new File... and it always say false.
@piet: i'm running test to see at which characters appears and if some are alwas here when it fail and never when it don't. thanks for the idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that your new filename is a Base64-encoded hash-value I'm pretty sure the `rename` will fail in those cases where the new filename contains a `/`. When trying to rename the file to `"abc/def"` `renameTo` will interpret the `abc`-part as a directory. Since this directory does not exist `renameTo` will fail (it does not implicitly create it).

Comment: For a file name safe Base64: [Base64.getUrlEncoder().withoutPadding()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Base64.html). Minus and underline instead, do not pad.

Comment: You're right, it's totally the / fault. However, the withoutPadding didn't get rid of that, it just delete the = at the end. I'll search for a correct Base64-encoded hashvalue without thoses / . thanks!

Comment: oh, my bad, the proposed encoder did work, i just didn't see the "Url" part. So Base64.getUrlEncoder().encodeToString(hash) is enough, as said WithoutPadding just get rid of the last  character =